# Generate algebraic expression at compile time in D

Tags: metaprogramming, d

Let's consider a function defined as follows:

```
f(n, x) = F(n, x, f(n-1, x))
f(0, x) = g(x)
```

In my program the value of `n` is always known at compile time. I want to optimize my program and avoid loops or recursive calls in this function. Whole expression for `f(n, x)` should be generated at compile time in order to allow compiler optimize it.

The direct solution is "manually" generate a string containing this expression and use `mixin` statement. I don't like this way.

Is compiler able/supposed to unfold a recursion with known depth?

I.e. will the following function be optimized in the way I want:

```
double f(uint n)(double x)
{
    static if(n == 0)
        return g(x);
    else
        return F(n, x, f!(n-1)(x));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no *guarantees* for optimizations in language specification as far as I know. Though your examples looks pretty trivial to optimize for compiler.

**Simple experiment**:
I have written stub functions g() and F() that do some simple calculations. Compiled with 
dmd -gc -O -inline". Checked with objdump:

```
0000000000426860 <_Dmain>:
  426860:   55                      push   %rbp
  426861:   48 8b ec                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  426864:   f2 48 0f 10 05 2b a7    rex.W movsd 0x2a72b(%rip),%xmm0        # 450f98 <_IO_stdin_used+0x38>
  42686b:   02 00 
  42686d:   be 0a 00 00 00          mov    $0xa,%esi
  426872:   48 bf 28 10 66 00 00    movabs $0x661028,%rdi
  426879:   00 00 00 
  42687c:   e8 6f 01 00 00          callq  4269f0 <_D3std5stdio4File14__T5writeTdTaZ5writeMFdaZv>
  426881:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  426883:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  426884:   c3                      retq
```

As you can see, everything was actually calculated during compilation and replaced with single numeric value that gets immediately printed as an argument to writeln. I have also checked modification where x get read at run-time and there are no calls to f() either. ASM listing is rather long there so I won't copy it.

Also, if your parameters are known at compile-time, then, probably, **CTFE** ( Compile Time Function Evaluation ) is a better solution as it is guaranteed.